# test automation theoretical framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I know [ISTQB](http://www.istqb.org/) [ASTQB](https://www.astqb.org/) provide theoretical framework for all kind of test activities and certifications. dose any body know organization or an entity which provides theoretical framework only for *automated testing*? or any forum (not-tool specific) do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Istqb extension for automated testing.  But it's not released yet http://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/test-automation-engineer.html

Answer (score 1):

Sqaforums dot Com has info on all automation FrameworkS .

Answer (score 0):

There is [this Advanced Level Test Automation Engineer Syllabus](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/48-advanced-level-test-automation-engineer-documents/201-advanced-test-automation-engineer-syllabus-ga-2016.html) from Oct 2016.

And there is a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937538087) scheduled for July 1, 2019.

Comment: Apparently the release date has been moved back a year.  July 1, 2020